# Multiple pop up in ContentPage Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uwp

For UWP, there is a feature [Show multiple popup views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/show-multiple-views) Which will split the form in another window and float over other applications.

Just like some video application, you could pop up the video to watch it while you browse video list page.

Is there any feature for Xamarin?

Comment: I think no way. you given link for system or 64 bit system, android, iOS  are ARM

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.forms, you could use `Popup Page Plugin`. It allows to open Xamarin.Forms pages as a popup that can be shared across iOS, 
Android and UWP (macOS supporting will be soon). Also the plugin allows to use very simple and flexible animations for showing popup pages.

You could download the source file from the GitHub. https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup.git

[image]

Comment: For checking the read.md, the popup windows will block the application. I need application is not blocked. Just like multiple view, after you pop up the windows, you will also be able to click anything bebind the popup window. Something like [Demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dongzhong/ImageAndVideoStore/master/Apps/MoveFloatingWindow.gif).

Comment: Is the FloatingWindow in this app? When you make the app background, the FloatingWindow still be there?